# R Package Data Files: Data Downloaded From Cloud is Inaccessible

Tags: r, package, cran, data-files

There is an R data package I would like to submit to CRAN, but the data is too large. Therefore, I want to design the package so it comes with samples of the full data and users can choose to replace the sample data with the full data.

I wrote a function that lets users download the full data from the cloud. However, once the full data is downloaded, it is inaccessible.

I would be grateful for your help making it so that the full data replaces the sample data.

Example:

```
# install and load the package
library(devtools)
install_github("stephbuon/hansardr")
library(hansardr)

# Read the sample data
data(hansard_1800)
```

Then you can download the full Hansard corpus from the cloud:

```
download_hansard()
```

The full data will be downloaded to the package's data folder (see: `list.files(paste0(.libPaths(), "/hansardr/data"))`)

However, when I use `data(hansard_1800)` I still only see the sample data. My hope is that `data(hansard_1800)` would now allow the user to access the full data.

Thanks so much for your help.